# How to add image on gif using Pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Actually I am doing some experiments with python but I came to the point where I want to add an image on a transparent GIF with dimensions of the image.

I am getting an error of `bad transparency mask`.
Code -

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
background = Image.open(...)
animated_gif = Image.open(...)

frames = []
for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(animated_gif):
frame = frame.copy()

frame.paste(background, mask=bg)
frames.append(frame)
frames[0].save('output.gif', save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:])
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how what you have tried and what exactly is causing the error.

Comment: code link - http://pastie.org/p/4l5vuBmgFAATf5PE3DkOhU

Comment: After running the above code I am getting error -> ValueError: bad transparency mask

Comment: Don't put links to code in your question — put the code in your question here.

Comment: I don't know what's the point to downvote the question if you can suggest it?

Comment: Because it can up-voted if you fix it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer of my question...

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
background = Image.open("img.jpg")
animated_gif = Image.open("GIFF.gif")

frames = []
for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(animated_gif):
    output = background.copy()
    frame_px = frame.load()
    output_px = output.load()
    transparent_foreground = frame.convert('RGBA')
    transparent_foreground_px = transparent_foreground.load()
    for x in range(frame.width):
        for y in range(frame.height):
            if frame_px[x, y] in (frame.info["background"], frame.info["transparency"]):
                continue
            output_px[x, y] = transparent_foreground_px[x, y]
    frames.append(output)

frames[0].save('output.gif', save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:-1])
```

Comment: I am getting this error while executing this code. https://ibb.co/PWK2KPr. Can you please help

Answer (score 0):

```
import Image
background = Image.open("test1.png")
foreground = Image.open("test2.png")
background.paste(foreground, (0, 0), foreground)
background.show()
```

I will explain the parameters for .paste() function.
first - the image to paste
second - coordinates
third - This indicates a mask that will be used to paste the image. If you pass a image with transparency, then the alpha channel is used as mask.

If this is not what you want to do, please add a comment for your need.

Comment: If you still have 'bad transparency mask', then use bg.paste(fg, (0, 0), fg.convert('RGBA')) for the mask parameter to make sure the background contains transparency in all cases.

Comment: No, my friend. for the background I am using JPEG or PNG image format and for the foreground I am using transparent GIF.

Comment: Have you tried it out to set a transparent GIF background and use PNG image for the foreground to merge them? I think what you need is to merge those two images?

Comment: Yes. You got it.

Comment: you can refer my code link - http://pastie.org/p/4l5vuBmgFAATf5PE3DkOhU